# How do I implement "If-Modified-Since" header on a node server?

Tags: http-headers, cache-control, node-js

My web-application is running on a node server on azure. I need to implement the "If-Modified-Since" header on this server. Could you please guide me how to do this?

I tried implementing by setting the header in server.js file, but it is not working apparently.